# How to calculate $\lim_{x\to 1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\frac{y^{3/2}}{\sqrt{x - y}}$ when $x>1$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, definite-integrals

Numerically, it looks that the limit is

$$\lim_{x\to 1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\frac{y^{3/2}}{\sqrt{x - y}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log(1 - x) + cte $$,

but I have not been able to demonstrate it analytically. Does anyone have a idea on how to deal with this limit?

Comment: Hont: Lebesgue's monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: The integral does not converge when $x\to 1$.

Comment: Of course it doesn't converge when x=1, but we are studying how is this divergence when we approach to x=1 from some x>1. Numerically it looks as a logarithmic divergence, but how could we demonstrate that?

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: From what I recall, the MCT does not require the limit $\int f$ to be finite (it can be $+\infty$); it just states that if $f_n\nearrow f$ and each $f_n$ is measurable and non-negative, then $f$ is and $\int f_n \to \int f$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you advance, compute the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-y}}$ at the point $x=1$

$$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-y}} = {\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-y}}}-\frac{1}{2}\, \left( 1-y \right) ^{-3/2} \left( x-1
 \right) +O \left(  \left( x-1 \right) ^{2} \right) $$

$$ \implies \frac{1}{\sqrt{x-y}} \sim {\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-y}}}. $$

So, when $x$ close to $1$, our integral behaves as

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{ y^{3/2} }{\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt {x-y}}dy \sim \int_{0}^{1} \frac{ y^{3/2} }{\sqrt{1-y^2}\sqrt {1-y}}dy$$

$$=\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac{ \left( -u+1 \right)^{3/2}}{\sqrt {-u+2}u}}{du}\sim \int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac {1}{\sqrt {2}u}}{du}.$$

The last integral does not converge. Note that, we used the change of variables $1-y=u$ and

$$ \frac{ ( -u+1 )^{3/2}}{\sqrt{-u+2}u} \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\,u} \quad \mathrm{when}\quad u\sim 0.$$

Comment: I have found how to handle with this problem. The key point is to use the following integral representation of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-y}}$:

Answer (score 1):

I have found how to handle with this problem. The key point is to use the following integral representation of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-y}}$:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-y}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{da}{\sqrt{\pi}} e^{-a(x-y)}$.

Using Mathematica, we can carry out the integral over $y$ and $a$ (in this order), obtaining a complex result in terms of generalized hypergeometric functions

$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\frac{y^{3/2}}{\sqrt{x - y}} = 
\frac{8 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} \left(2 x \Gamma \left(\frac{5}{4}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{9}{4}\right) \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};\frac{1}{2},\frac{7}{4};\frac{1}{x^2}\right)+\Gamma \left(\frac{7}{4}\right)^2 \, _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};\frac{3}{2},\frac{9}{4};\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)}{15 x^{3/2}}.$

After that, the limit is easily obtained by Mathematica as

$\lim_{x\to 1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{dy}{\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}\frac{y^{3/2}}{\sqrt{x - y}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\log(1-x) + \frac{75 \log (2)-4 \left(5 \, _3F_2\left(\frac{1}{4},1,\frac{3}{2};\frac{5}{4},\frac{7}{4};1\right)+\, _3F_2\left(\frac{3}{4},1,\frac{3}{2};\frac{7}{4},\frac{9}{4};1\right)\right)}{15 \sqrt{2}}$,

which is the expected result.

Thanks by your help.

Comment: Why is there still a $\log(1-x)$ in the RHS if you're taking $x\to 1$?

Comment: Because I was looking for the behavior of the divergence of the integral when $x\to 1$, it is to say, if you are close enough to $x=1$ and $x>1$, the integral behaves as a logarithm plus a constant (at first order). Probably there is a better notation for that than a limit.